# Min Coin Change Problem - Lowest Common Multiple

Tags: algorithm

This video covers an implementation of the min coins to make change.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

The place I'm not clear on is where the interviewer goes into the details of optimization, starting from here.

https://youtu.be/HWW-jA6YjHk?t=1875

He suggests that to make the min number of coins, using denominations [25, 10, 1], we only need to use the algorithm to make change for numbers above 50 cents, after which we can safely just use 25 cents. So if the number was $100.10, we can use 25 cents till we hit 50 cents at which time we need to use the algorithm to compute the precise value.

This makes sense for the list of denominations give [25, 10, 1]. To get the breakpoint figure he suggests using LCM of the denominations which is 50 in this case.

```
For example 
32 - 25 * 1 + 1 * 7 = 8 coins. But with 10 cents we can do 
32 - 10 * 3 + 1 * 2 = 5 coins.
```

So we cannot just assume 25 cents is going to be included in the minimum number of coins calculation.

Here is my question --

Suppose we have denominations [25, 10, 5, 1], the lcm is still 50. But there is no min solution for any number over 25 cents has doesn't include the 25.

eg -

```
32 - 25 * 1 + 5 * 1 + 1 * 2 = 4 coins. 
32 - 10 * 3 + 1 * 2 = 5 coins
```

So shouldn't the breakpoint be 25 cents in this case? Instead of the lcm?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LCM of the values provides a minimum upper bound on the "break point", that point at which we cannot blithely assume that the highest-denomination coin is part of the solution.  A little number theory will prove that the LCM is a boundary.

50 is the LCM of {25, 10}.  For any amount >= 50, any combination including at least 5*10 can replace that element by 2*25, reducing the coin count.  This argument applies to all other coins and combinations thereof.  This simple demonstration does not universally apply *below* the LCM; there will be amounts that serve as counterexamples.

To keep the overall algorithm easy to understand and maintain, we use only the two phases: largest coin above that breakpoint, and full DP solution below -- where, for most applications, even a brute-force solution is generally efficient enough for practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

They didn't say we can't use 25 when the input is lower than the break point. They suggested that a good optimisation can be to use the highest denomination until we reduce the number to the break point (because that is *guaranteed* to be the least number of coins needed for that portion) and then switch to the more resource-intensive algorithm to count the rest of the needed coins.

Comment: That part is clear, my question is more specifically why isn't the breakpoint 25, since there are no sets between .25 - .50, where 25 is not in the minimum coin set.

Comment: @SushantRao because under the break point, the coin distribution is idiosyncratic, depending on the given target and denominations. The "break point" was defined by the interviewer as the point where we switch from the simple algorithm (dividing by the largest denomination) to the more complex, dynamic program.

Comment: But it's not idiosyncratic because there is *always* a .25 coin being used in the minimum between .25 and .50 as well. Can you give me an example where this is not true?

Comment: @SushantRao You gave an example yourself where 25 is not used between 25 and 50: 32: 10 * 3 + 1 * 2 = 5, when the denominations are [25, 10, 1]. That's why they suggested using the dynamic program under the break point (because the simple LCM won't be reliable there). The rule you've suggested may apply (at least) to the specific denominations, [25, 10, 5, 1]. But how does having a rule for one set of denominations help us generally?